# Get json array from php to javascript with $.getJSON()

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have application.php page where json array is echoed with php. On the client i want to get the json array with $.getJSON() on button click when form is submitted(submitHandler). The problem is that if I run alert() or console.log() in $.getJSON() nothing happens(i only see GET execution in console).

Code:

```
$.getJSON('../views/application.php', function(data) {
     alert('alert1');
     if(data) {
         document.write(data.resp);
         alert('alert2');
     }
     else {
         alert('error');
     }
 });

GET http://localhost/app/views/application.php
```

Comment: Maybe on `$_SESSION`, temp file, database?

Comment: The point of using session variables is that they are not visible to client side?

Comment: I don't think you're using ajax in the way the you should be? If you execute your first "post" and php generates a result, you need to have PHP "echo" that result so that it can be read as the ajax response, then you can use that value in your second ajax request. Is this not how you're doing it?

Comment: where do you want to store the data ? local-storage adding to Mihai lorga comment

Comment: your question is vague ..could you clarify  what you are trying to do ?

Comment: Are the two post request in the same page ?

Comment: Yes they are in the same page.

Comment: Does your application.php return valid json, with a valid header?
try to add .fail(function(j,t,e) { console.error(e); }) after getJSON.

Comment: I got error: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character               return window.JSON.parse( data + "" );

Comment: In application.php i create json data like that:                         echo json_encode($responseVar);

Answer (score 1):

you can use var temp in your script and store your data inside that variable.

```
 var x;
```

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
      x='<?php echo $comparisonResult; ?>';
   </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a use case for [sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage) or [cookies](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie).

[Use sessionstorage if you don't need to support IE7](http://caniuse.com/namevalue-storage).

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is to return the needed server data in the response of your first post request, just like this :

```
  $.post( "/first.php", function( serverData ) {
     var param = serverData.something;
     ...
     $.post( "/second.php", param, function( data ) {
        ...
     });
  });
```

If you are using the two request in two different pages, you can store serverData in [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Web%2FGuide%2FDOM%2FStorage).

**Edit after your clarification:**

If you need to get data before ajax post when you click on a button, you can do this way :

```
$("#second-button").click(function() {
   $.getJSON("/data.php", function (serverData) {
      var param = serverData.something;
      $.post("/second.php", param, function(data) {
         ...
      });
   }
});
```

**Edit 2**

For some reason (wrong url, invalid json, and so on) your $.getJSON fail.

Try this for debug:

```
$.getJSON("/data.php", function (serverData) {
   console.log(serverData);
}).fail(function(j, t, e) {
   console.error(e);
});
```

Comment: Now i see json array on my page which is echoed in php script. I tryied to get the json data with $.getJSON(), but nothing happend. Do you have any idea what i am doing wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by nothing happened, did you get an error, or serverData is empty? It's difficult to give you relevant advice without see the complete code. Could you edit your question and add what you tried?